# change controller $scope from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive

I have a controller:

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.clicked = false;
}
```

and a directive:

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            elem.bind('click', function() {
                // need to update controller $scope.clicked value
            });
        },

        template: '<div>click me</div>'; 
        replace: true;
    }
}
```

and I´m using it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

How can I change the controller value of $scope.clicked ?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't use isolated scope in your directive, you can use `scope.$parent.clicked` to access the parent scope property.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$parent.clicked = ...
            });
        },
```

Comment: scope.$parent saved me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using `scope.$parent` to update or access the parent scope values, you can `two way bind` the controller variable that needs to be updated into your directive, so your directive becomes:

```
function myDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
         clicked: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            elem.bind('click', function() {
                // need to update controller $scope.clicked value
                $scope.clicked = !$scope.clicked;
            });
        },

        template: '<div>click me</div>'; 
        replace: true;
    }
}
```

now pass this `clicked` from parent:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as parentVm">
    <my-directive clicked="parentVm.clicked"></my-directive>
</div>

function myController() {
    var parentVm = this;
    parentVm.clicked = false;
}
```

I would recommend reading up on using `controllerAs` syntax for your controller as that would really solidify the concept of using two way binding here.

Comment: Nice, for mentioning use of controllerAs syntax

Comment: You have misused `controller as` ability.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use $scope.$emit for such purposes. It allows to send data from directive to the controller.
You should create custom listener  in your controller:

```
$scope.$on('cliked-from-directive', function(event, data){
        console.log(data)
})
```

As you can see, now you have full access to your controller scope and you can do whatever you want. And in your directive just to use `scope.$emit`
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

```
        elem.bind('click', function() {
          scope.$emit('cliked-from-directive', {a:10}) 
        });
```

Here I've created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiyanov/0gbhu8je/1/) for you